# How to automatically add a new token to the select box?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, select, antd

I am trying to use the `automatic tokenization` select box of [antd](https://ant.design/components/select/) as:

```
 import { Select } from 'antd';

const Option = Select.Option;

const children = [];
for (let i = 10; i < 36; i++) {
children.push(<Option key={i.toString(36) + i}>{i.toString(36) + i}</Option>);
}

function handleChange(value) {
console.log(`selected ${value}`);
}

ReactDOM.render(
<Select mode="tags" style={{ width: '100%' }} onChange={handleChange} tokenSeparators={[',']}>
    {children}
</Select>,
mountNode,
);
```

Now I want to dynamically add a token/tag into the select box. The tokenization box looks as:

[image]

I am trying to push a new token as:

```
children.push(<Option key={newKey}>{newValue}</Option>
```

Although, it gets to the select box but does not appear as one of the selected token in the box. How could I do this? I have to manually select the token added. I want the new token added to automatically appear in the select box.

Comment: I deleted my previous comment. You need to use state and pass the value of children into state.

Answer (score 0):

You should `useState` to update your children:

```
import { Select, useState } from 'antd';

const Option = Select.Option;

const children = [];
for (let i = 10; i < 36; i++) {
  children.push(<Option key={i.toString(36) + i}>{i.toString(36) + i}</Option>);
}

function SelectBox () {
  const [children, setChildren] = useState(children);
  return <Select mode="tags" style={{ width: '100%' }} onChange={(value) => setChildren([...children, value])} tokenSeparators={[',']}>
    {children}
  </Select>
}

ReactDOM.render(<SelectBox />, mountNode);
```

Check the docs **[here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html)**.

Here's the equivalence of this code:

```
default class Select extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    const children = [];
    for (let i = 10; i < 36; i++) {
      children.push(<Option key={i.toString(36) + i}>{i.toString(36) + i}</Option>);
    }
    this.setState({children});
  }
  render () {
    const { children } = this.state;
    return <Select mode="tags" style={{ width: '100%' }} onChange={(value) => this.setState({children: [...children, value]})} tokenSeparators={[',']}>
      {children}
    </Select>
  }
}
```

Comment: Is there another way around? Looks like my version of `antd` does not support `useState`.

Comment: Could we discuss this here at https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193324/migrated-from-https-stackoverflow-com-questions-56128736-how-to-automatically-a